# Laplace transform of first passage time distribution, $f_{T_a}(t)$, in Weiner process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, laplace-transform

We have the p.d.f. of first passage time, $T_a$, to a fixed level $a$ as:$$f_{T_a}(t)=\frac a{\sqrt{2π}}\cdot t^\frac{-3}{2}\cdot e^\frac{-a^2}{2t},\;t>0.$$ We need to find the p.d.f. of $T_{a+b}$. For this purpose, we may first find the Laplace transform of $T_{a+b}$ and then taking the inverse Laplace transform we can get the p.d.f. of $T_{a+b}. $ Since $\mathscr{L}\{f_{T_{a+b}}(t)\}=\mathscr{L}\{f_{T_a}(t)\}\cdot\mathscr{L}\{f_{T_b}(t)\}$, where $T_a$ and $(T_{a+b}-T_a)$ are two independent random variables and $T_{a+b}=T_a+(T_{a+b}-T_a).$

In a book on *Stochastic processes,* I found out that $\mathscr L\{f_{T_a}(t)\}=\bar h_a(s)=e^{-a\sqrt{2s}}$. But I want to know how to find it actually. I am not able to do that yet based on my knowledge regarding Laplace transform. Mainly the $t$ in the denominator in the exponent of $e$ in $f_{T_a}$ is causing problems for me.

So please help me to find it. Any kind of suggestion will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(s)=\frac a{\sqrt{2π}}\int_0^\infty t^\frac{-3}{2}e^\frac{-a^2}{2t}e^{-st}dt=(x=\sqrt t)\,\, \frac a{\sqrt{2π}}\int_0^\infty  e^\frac{-a^2}{2x^2}e^{-sx^2}\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
$$=(t=\sqrt s x)\,\,\frac {2a\sqrt s}{\sqrt{2π}}\int_0^\infty  e^\frac{-sa^2}{2t^2}e^{-t^2}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{2c}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty  e^{-t^2-\frac{c^2}{t^2}}\frac{dt}{t^2} \,\,\, (c=\frac{a\sqrt s}{\sqrt2})$$ $$=\frac{2\,c\,e^{-2c}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty  e^{-(t-\frac{c}{t})^2}\frac{dt}{t^2} $$
Making change $x=\frac{c}{t}$
$$F(s)=\frac{2\,e^{-2c}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty  e^{-(x-\frac{c}{x})^2}dx$$
$$2 F(s)=\frac{2\,e^{-2c}}{\sqrt\pi}\Bigl( \int_0^\infty  e^{-(t-\frac{c}{t})^2}\frac{c\,dt}{t^2}+\int_0^\infty  e^{-(t-\frac{c}{t})^2}dt\Bigr)=\frac{2\,e^{-2c}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty  e^{-(t-\frac{c}{t})^2}d\Bigl(t-\frac{c}{t}\Bigr)$$
$$2 F(s)=\frac{2\,e^{-2c}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=2\,e^{-2c}$$
$$F(s)=e^{-a\sqrt{2s}}$$

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your precious time. It was quite great for me to learn this procedure of evaluating a Laplace transform. Sir I would like to know, how could you come up with these successive substitutions? I mean if I can grasp your idea then I might be able to use it in future while calculating such Laplace transforms.

Comment: @Dhrubajyoti Bhattacharjee I'm pleased that I could help. In fact this substitution is not related to Laplace transform - this is so called a Master theorem which states that  $\int_0^\infty  e^{-(t-\frac{c}{t})^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-t^2}dt$ - I just applied it to your Laplace transform. As for learning Laplace transform I would recommend MATHEMATICAL METHODS FOR PHYSICISTS by George B. Arfken and others, chapter 20.7 LAPLACE TRANSFORMS, p. 1008

Comment: Thanks sir will surely check it out.